# Import data from Excel to website using selenium python

Tags: angularjs, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu

I've a project, importing data from Excel sheet to a webpage call rpag.com and I'm totally new to selenium automation, could anyone please help me.

Inside the webpage, there are 4steps

In step1 once we click, it will load a second/child page(within the page).
Under child page theres a table in that table we've searchable boxes, I want my Excel data to get there.

Note: webpage is in angularjs

Thanks for your help, hope someone could help me

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I used few import statements but it's not working... I could able to get inside the webpage and able click on the child page... Afterwards struck...from selenium import we driver...from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys....from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import select.... import time THEN  driver=we driver.chrome(executable path of selenium chrome driver)...driver.get(webpage link)...then using class name selected step1 ...then got the table now I have to import data from Excel to searchable boxes

Comment: Can you please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and edit your question to add the code you've tried and the errors you are getting?